# How to enumerate MTP and PTP devices

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, mtp, wpd, ptp

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6653205/327083) explains how to use WMI to find attached USB mass storage devices by drive letter but I am trying to find the names of (or UNC paths to) attached MTP or PTP devices, such as attached cameras or mobile devices which are mounted without a drive letter, so that I can crawl their directories to search for images.  How can I do this?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/29144536/327083

Comment: also related (no answer) :https://stackoverflow.com/q/29194124/327083

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8234407/327083

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389295(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that having MTP device name will not allow you to crawl it directories or search for images with methods you use for simple PC filesystems. It's only simplified view from Windows Explorer, not really state of things.

I don't know how exeactly do it with Delphi, but there is a [Windows Portable Devices API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389005(v=vs.85).aspx) and it all uses COM, so I beleave there is a way to get it works even on Delphi.

Another way you may try, is using [libmtp](https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/code/ci/master/tree/) it's a plain C library, you definetely [can call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405991/calling-functions-from-a-c-dll-in-delphi) it's dll methods from Delphi with some helper code.

If you want just names, you can find names of attached WPD devices (Windows Portable Devices, they are using MTP and PTP protocols) using SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty WinApi function.

First you need to call [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069(v=vs.85).aspx) with GUID_DEVINTERFACE_WPD (it is defined in PortableDevice.h but you can find it easy in google
{6AC27878-A6FA-4155-BA85-F98F491D4F33} )

Then iterate on devices using SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo, get id of each device from WPD cathegory with CM_Get_Device_ID function call and pass it to SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty with SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME (or SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, maybe you should try different parameters)

There are a lot of samples of using this functions, for example this one:
[SetupDiGetDeviceProperty usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438366/setupdigetdeviceproperty-usage-example)